# Multidicts and Sets

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set

I have `n` csv's that I created a multidict with:

```
for name in filenames:
    with open(path+name) as openFile:
    reader = csv.reader(openFile)
    for line in reader:
        if line[1] in t:
            pass
        elif line[1] == 'filer_name':
            pass
        else:
            t[name[:-8]].add(line[1])
```

This works and outputs a multidict (from collections import defaultdict) with the form:

```
{company name: {other_company_1, other_company_2,...}}
```

There are n companies with n sets of other companies. So now, I want to say for other_company in each key, check if other_company is in the values of another company. Example:

```
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {Apple : {Samsung, Qualcomm, NVidia}},{Microsoft: {Samsung, Alcoa, Dollar Tree}})
```

I want Samsung to be returned, but it needs to search each set of values for every key. So if Dollar Tree was in the values of a third company, it would find Dollar Tree too.

Attempt at solution:

```
for key, values in t.items():
    for item in values:
        if item in values:
            print(item)
```

Additionally, is there a way to return the `other_company` if it occurs 3 or more times? 4 or more times? m or more times? in the multidict.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a counter:

```
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter()
for key, values in t.items():
    for item in values:
        cnt[item] += 1

print([comp for comp in cnt if cnt[comp] > 1])
```

You can change 1 to 2,3 if you want N occurrences.

Comment: I tried this; unfortunately, it doesn't work. It returns: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x00...92B8AF8>.

Comment: @xp1123 : forgot to add [] for making a list. Try the new version.

Comment: Never mind. It works when a list is inside the print statement. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need the inner `for` loop. Just `cnt.update(items)` instead.

Comment: You also don't need `for key, values in t.items():` since you never use `key`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare every pair of company sets which are the values of your main dictionary so you can use `itertools.combinations` to crate that pairs and then check the intersection with `set.intersection` to return the intersections.

```
for (comp1,comp_set1),(comp2,comp_set2) in combinations(mydict.items(),2) :
     print '{} and {}'.fromat(com1,com2),comp_set1.intersections(comp_set2)
```